# How to make page load animation like in Youtube

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make the page load elements before the content is fully loaded? Is there a name for this animation style? Youtube, Binance and many other sites use this kind of content loading, but all the tutorials I could find are related to the usual loading spinners

[image: Page before fully loaded]

Comment: It's called skeleton. There are a few plugins for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Reactjs then you can use the skeleton-loading package from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loading-skeleton)

If you want to make it with only HTML, CSS and javascript, then you can learn to make it with this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZVug65gW-fc)